# Всё ли верно тут написано? Больше всего смущает: "спасибо вам за дружбу" или "за вашу дружбу"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, выбор-слов, выбор-варианта, диалог

*Самая большая удача в жизни — это иметь офигенных друзей! Пацаны, спасибо вам за дружбу и за то, что в этот день были со мной!*

Comment: Всё верно точно? А вам за дружбу это не ошибка? Может лучше за вашу дружбу?

Comment: Нет, не ошибка. "За вашу дружбу" выглядело бы как неумелый перевод с английского (thanks for your friendship/understanding, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Всё написано верно, при этом оба варианта вполне корректны: и "спасибо вам за дружбу", и "спасибо за вашу дружбу". Что касается последнего выражения, оно и правда может показаться калькой с английского *thanks for your friendship*, однако ошибкой не является. В подтверждение тому можно отыскать множество примеров и схожих выражений из "Нацкорпуса", приведу лишь несколько.

***Спасибо вам** сердечное **за вашу дружбу** и любовь к экспедиции.* [П. К. Козлов. Географический дневник Тибетской экспедиции 1923-1926 гг. №2 (1924)]

***Спасибо за вашу дружбу** и ко мне, и к моему лучшему другу В. Г., но вы слишком мрачно смотрите на мое положение.* [А. Б. Гольденвейзер. Вблизи Толстого (1910)]

*Но я благодарен вам за доверие, **благодарен за вашу дружбу**, ваше хорошее чувство ко мне.* [Е. А. Салиас. Кудесник (1885)]

*Я, в умилении сердца, **благодарю Вас за Вашу дружбу**, которая греет меня, старика.* [И. А. Гончаров. Письма (1842-1859)]

*Если Вы, рожденная в звании гораздо выше моего, найдете необоснованной дерзостью с моей стороны притязать на руку внучки моего покровителя, скажите это прямо, и я останусь так же **признателен за Вашу дружбу**, как был признателен за Вашу доброту, когда в первый раз обедал во дворце Вашего отца.* [Е. Ахматова [перевод романа Э. Булвер-Литтона с английского]. Кенелм Чиллингли, его приключения и взгляды на жизнь (1873)]